# How to avoid auto rounding done by NumberFormat(Locale).format() method while formatting a value?

Tags: java, currency-formatting

Okay so my problem is..  when I try to format a number into a currency string(e.g. 10.23 to $10.23), using format method of NumberFormat class, it automatically rounds off the value. And this is occurring specifically when I pass Japanese/Korean locale to NumberFormat's getCurrencyInstance() method. In case of US locale, things are working fine. Here is the snippet that will give a clear picture of the problem:

```
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(123.456);
        String str = formatter.format(bd);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str); // Output is coming ¥123 instead of ¥123.456
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or doing something illogical. If not then Is there a way to prevent this round off? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nambari is right. Take a look at this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(123.456);
String str = nf.format(bd);
System.out.println("" + nf.getMaximumFractionDigits()); //prints out 0
System.out.println(str);
```

It seems like the default fraction digits for Japan is set to 0. When I do the same for Locale.US it apparently defaults to 2. Use Nambari's answer and setMaximumFractionDigits.

As to why, thanks to @Lee Meador for pointing it out in a comment, Japanese currencies do not use decimal places (aka the single yen is as far as you can go).

From a wikipedia article on the Japanese yen:

*"Coins in denominations of less than 1 yen became invalid on December 31, 1953, following enforcement of the Small Currency Disposition and Fractional Rounding in Payments Act"*

Since I'm too lazy to look up the Korean currency, I'm just going to assume they have a similar situation.

Comment: Just as the US and EU use two digits standard with dollars and euros, respectively, Japan uses zero digits as standard. Most people would be confused if they went into a store or looked at an accounting report and saw the dollars (or euros) to anything except two digits. There are some things that are sold with tenths of cents but not too many. The only other common usage is to show whole dollars and round. This can be done on a US tax filing, for example.

Comment: This is useful info. Thanks.

Comment: +1. @ARC: My answers tells fix, but this answers explains issue very well.

Comment: But this is working only for currencyInstances. What about others?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need to set `setMaximumFractionDigits` for the `NumberFormat`

```
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(123.456);  
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4); //Replace 4 with whatever value applicable for you.
    String str = formatter.format(bd);
```

output:

```
￥123.456
```

Comment: I already know that method, but I don't want to limit the decimal places in the output. Why format method behaves differently for locales like JP/KR?

Comment: @user1887318: When you use getInstance(locale) it seems behavior will be locale specific implementation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html and http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=210

Comment: I did not fully understand what you said. Let me give you more details. I want NumberFormat to format my input as per the locale. If my input is 123456.789, then I want the output as 
$123,456.789  in Locale.US, 
123 456,789€ in Locale.FRANCE,
123.456,789€ in Locale.GERMANY and 
¥123,456.789 in Locale.JAPAN.
Correct me if I am wrong but that is how format method should behave.

Comment: As @ARC explained, somehow Japan local has 0 as fraction digits. As said in my previous comment, when you use getInstance(locale), behavior is based on locale definition.

Comment: Some locales have different defaults for the number of digits displayed after the decimal point. Nambari's solution for setting the max fraction digits appears to be correct.